# Which character set in Oracle supports the Microsoft heavy arrow

Tags: sql, oracle, character-encoding

As the title states, which character set in the Oracle databases supports the Microsoft heavy arrow?  The heavy arrow (as it has been told to me) is the arrow that is generated when you type `-->` into a microsoft word document and it gives you something that looks like this **->**

I would paste it here but I just get: 

Comment: Unicode? http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2794/index.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably part of a different font (wingdings), not a special character in a standard font (e.g. Arial).  Therefore, you would have to use some kind of application encoding to get this as part of a regular text -- for instance, when your application sees `-->` it would replace it with the wingdings character, the same way Word does.

Comment: Saving a document as “Word XML” confirms that the symbol is stored using Private Use codepoint U+F0E0 with the Wingdings font. So it’s not an interoperable character at all, only a glyph from a specific font. You do not need a special encoding; rather, a special interpretation for the code point, which has no meaning except as per private agreements. (Incidentally, in the Calibri font, the common arrow character U+2192 “→” has a shape that resembles this symbol, especially if bold, but still differs from it.)